# Why have space in my text in my sas ods pdf

Tags: pdf, sas, ods

I want to make a pdf report in formula 1 GP, I have macro variables like the name of the GP, the year,... But in my pdf I have some space before or after my macro. I try to make some modification on my macro but without success. I put the result and a part of my code.

```
proc sql noprint;
  select trim(name) 
  into :gp_name
  from F1.race_data;
quit;

proc sql noprint;
  select trim(put(year , best.))
  into :gp_year
  from F1.race_data;
quit;

proc sql noprint;
  select trim(put(round , best.))
  into :gp_round
  from F1.race_data;
quit;
```

To make my pdf I have this

```
ODS PDF FILE= '/home/u59673531/SASII/Rapport_F1.pdf' style=rapport
    TITLE= 'Rapport GP F1'
    AUTHOR='ABC';
OPTIONS NODATE NONUMBER;
ODS ESCAPECHAR='^';
ODS PDF STARTPAGE=NEVER;

TITLE2 justify=LEFT  "Résumé du &gp_name";

ODS PDF TEXT="^{newline 1}";
ods text = "Voici le résumé du &gp_name sur le &gp_namegp pour le &gp_round e grand prix de la saison &gp_year se déroulant à &gp_local";

PROC PRINT DATA=F1.TABLE_GP NOOBS;
RUN;
```

And in my pdf I have this
[image]

How I can resolve the problem with the space in my text ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [TRIMMED option](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/sqlproc/n1tupenuhmu1j0n19d3curl9igt4.htm).

**TRIMMED**
*trims the leading and trailing blanks from values that are stored in a single macro variable.*

```
proc sql noprint;
  select trim(name) 
  into :gp_name TRIMMED
  from F1.race_data;
quit;
```

EDIT:

Example of doing multiple at once with formats.

```
proc sql noprint;
select name, 
       age, 
       today() format=worddate20.
into :name TRIMMED, 
     :age TRIMMED, 
     :date TRIMMED
from sashelp.class(obs=1);
quit;

%put |&name|;
%put |&age.|;
%put |&date.|;
```

Last Edit:

```
proc format;
  
   picture langtsfr (default=50) other='%d %B, %Y' 
                                 (datatype=date language=french);

run;

proc sql noprint;
select name, 
       age, 
       '01SEP2023'd format=langtsfr.
into :name TRIMMED, 
     :age TRIMMED, 
     :date TRIMMED
from sashelp.class(obs=1);
quit;

%put |&name|;
%put |&age.|;
%put |&date.|;
```

Comment: Thanks ! I was on the right track. And for a date is it also possible to remove these spaces? Or turn 2002-03-29 into March 29, 2022 altogether?

Comment: Where/how are you getting a date?

Comment: I have a date variable in the format 2002-03-29 in my table and I made a macro like this `proc sql noprint;
  select date 
  into :gp_date 
  from F1.race_data;
quit;
 `

Comment: Try adding a format. `proc sql noprint; select date format=worddate20. into gp_date from ....`

Comment: FYI you can do more than one value in a query at once, you don't need multiple queries for multiple macro variables.

Comment: You can use TRIMMED with any type of value being queried.  They all end up as text strings to be able to be stuffed in to a macro variable.

Comment: @Reeza I try with the format ddmmyy10. and I have May 2 , 1999. But I need to have my date in French and I can't find a French format. Do you know if format exist for special language ? Thanks for the tips

Comment: You have to roll your own format. Not sure why it's coming in as lower case though.

Answer (score 1):

You could also compute the entire text in a single query

```
proc sql noprint; 
  select catx(' ',
    "Voici le résumé du",  name,
    "sur le",              namegp,
    "pour le",             round,
    "e grand prix de la saison", year,
    "se déroulant à",      local
   )
   into
     :race_text trimmed
   from
     F1.race_data
/* where 
     row criteria?
 */
 ;

...

ods text = "&race_text";
```